# Height issues in display table concept

Tags: html, internet-explorer, css-tables

This is my code structure

```
<div class="display-table">
  <div class="display-tablecell">

  </div>
  <div class="display-tablecell">

  </div>
  <div class="display-tablecell">
    <div>
      <div class="display-table">
        <div class="display-tablecell"> /* height issue div*/
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

I have give height 100% to all div and its working in all major browsers but not working height 100% properly in IE browsers especially which I have commanded.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Make div 100% height of browser window](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1575141/make-div-100-height-of-browser-window)

Answer (score -1):

In order to use height: 100%, the parent container should have a fixed height(Eg: 500px).

Comment: This isn't quite true. The parent's height must be determinable. So if the html element is 100%, you can use 100% all the way down